# MySql Case not returning expected value on NULL

Tags: mysql, null, left-join, case

I have the following query:

```
SELECT  t1.id,
        t1.collection_date,
        t2.last_order_date,
        t2.hasOrders
FROM job_details AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  job_id, 
                MAX(date) AS last_order_date,
                (CASE COALESCE(MAX(date), '0000-01-01') WHEN '0000-01-01' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END) AS hasOrders
        FROM sales_orders
        GROUP BY job_id
        )
    AS t2
    ON t2.job_id = t1.id
```

I am expecting `t2.hasOrders` to be either `true` or `false` after the `CASE` part of the `LEFT JOIN` but I keep getting either `true` or `NULL` as [demonstrated here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2ALzP6sVWDTm9du9z3bwyp/0)

I know that `t2.date` will always return a valid date or the default column value of `0000-00-00`.

This is a simplified version of my query as the table the `LEFT JOIN` is querying is a temporary table.

Why do `NULL` values for `t2.date` not return my expected result?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

LINK TO DEMONSTATION - removed `where` part of query

**EDIT 2**

Expected result:

```
id      collection_date     last_order_date     hasOrders
1001    2019-02-07          2019-02-01          true
1002    2019-02-09          0000-01-01          false
```

Actual Result:

```
 id     collection_date     last_order_date     hasOrders
1001    2019-02-07          2019-02-01          true
1002    2019-02-09          NULL                NULL
```

**Edit 3**

Updated above query to include `group by` in `left join` part of query and changed `0000-00-00` to `0000-01-01` as suggested. Still not working as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure yet about the true / null behaviour, however my question is - what are you actually trying to achieve? I'm not clear what the 'MAX' function with in the sales_orders table should really do... If you only wanted to see the last order for every job / date, then I think you should apply the max on the outer statement.
Btw., as the answers below - when you are using aggregate functions such as 'MAX', I also believe you should use a 'Group by' statement.

Comment: @ErikReder I have a group by in the actual query, its mistakenly been left out when I simplified it for the question.

Comment: @ErikReder The max function is used in creating a temporary table which is used in the actual query because there is a lot of data and the query was taking too long.

Comment: So I think the issue is sales_order table does not have any entry on id 1002. Your temporary table therefore looks like
1001 2019-02-01 true --> only one row. So for the id 1002 the left table will find nothing to join and therefore put NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the CASE WHEN to the outer query since the inner CASE WHEN would never be executed when there are no rows in `sales_orders`

```
SELECT  t1.id,
    t1.collection_date,
    COALESCE(t2.last_order_date, '0001-01-01') order_date,
    CASE COALESCE(t2.last_order_date, '0001-01-01') 
      WHEN '0001-01-01' THEN 'false' 
      ELSE 'true' 
    END flag
FROM job_details AS t1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT  job_id, MAX(date) AS last_order_date
   FROM sales_orders
   GROUP BY job_id
  ) AS t2
 ON t2.job_id = t1.id
```

Comment: My actual query does use group by on the left join, I missed off the demo (sorry). I have tried changing the dates as suggested but get the same results.

Comment: Thanks. I think I misunderstood how left joins worked. Doing this would work if the data was to be processed / displayed but I was hoping to use the true / false result of the CASE part in a where statement but that wouldn't be possible as it would be an alias.

Answer (score 1):

I think by moving the 'Max' and group by to the outer statement, the logic should at least work fine (need to add the 'Coalesce' statement if you want to compute that column as well). Not sure performance wise, but I would first see if the result is generally fine. Hope the syntax is fine, haven't tested.

```
SELECT  t1.id,
        t1.collection_date,
        MAX(t2.last_order_date)
FROM job_details AS t1
        LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  job_id, 
                last_order_date
        FROM sales_orders
        )
    AS t2
    ON t2.job_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: Hmm, just noticed Joakim's answer below, which is probably better as it contains the COALESCE statement already. Looks fine to me. Anyway, maybe try the simple version above first, and then go for the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've to put `t1.collection_date <= '2019-02-09'` as for job_id 1002 date is `'2019-02-09'`

```
SELECT  t1.id,
        t1.collection_date,
        t2.order_date,
        t2.hasOrders
FROM job_details AS t1
    LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT  job_id, 
                MAX(date) AS order_date,
                (CASE COALESCE(MAX(date), '0000-00-00') WHEN '0000-00-00' THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END) AS hasOrders
        FROM sales_orders group by job_id
        )
    AS t2
    ON t2.job_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.collection_date <= '2019-02-09'
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the demo. The where statement should have been there.

Comment: can you please add your expected output @Gavin

Comment: I have added the expected and actual results